# PL/SQL, Execute Immediate troubles

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I learning Pl/SQL and have so problem with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

I check this:

```
 CREATE TABLE x(id number(10) );
```

and this work correctly. Currently i want do it with **BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE;END**, try:

```
BEGIN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE x(id number(10) );' ;
END
```

And i have error with 2 messages:

> 1. About symbol ";" was replaced to "end-of-file" to be continue
> 2. That we meet "end-of-file" symbol when it should be "; identity"

How i should correctly do it with BEGIN/EXECUTE IMMEDIATE/END ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dynamic SQL, you don't terminate the statement - remove this semi-colon:

```
... number(10) );'
                ^
               this
```

So:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE x(id number(10) )' ;
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> desc x
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER(10)

SQL>
```